# How to change to a directory with a leading -

Tags: directory, cd-command

I don't know why someone would make a directory with a leading hyphen, e.g. named "-1".  When I try to change to that directory, it says invalid option.

I tried putting "-1" in quotes but that didn't help either.  Can anyone tell me how to access these types of dirs?

```
$ ls -l
total 3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2 Dec  7 18:51 lastFailedBuild -> -1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2 Dec  7 18:51 lastUnstableBuild -> -1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 2 Dec  7 18:51 lastUnsuccessfulBuild -> -1
$ cd -1
-bash: cd: -1: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
$
```

Comment: Looks like this directory doesn't even exist.

Comment: For many GNU utilities you could use `--` to delimit options and arguments, i.e. `cd -- -1` could have worked if it had existed.

Answer (score 2):

You can anchor the name `-1` in the current directory by prefixing it with `./`. Then, then resulting name `./-1` does not start with a dash and `cd` will not try to interpret it as an option.